# Can I use AdMob in android apps published on Amazon Appstore?

Tags: android, admob, ads, amazon-appstore

Can I use AdMob ads in my apps on Amazon Appstore? If not, what ad networks can I use?

Comment: Hello dop2000, Can you please share, did you get success by using Ad-mob SDK for Amazon app store or you are using some else App store.
I am also working for an app to be uploaded on amazon app store.....

Comment: Yes, my app with AdMob was successfully approved.

Comment: For any one else hitting the link the answer is big No because Google Play services runtime support is not available in Kindle devices https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=11680&#11680

Comment: I think it's technically possible, the question is if the license allow this

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AdMob is an ad network which supports (in this context) Android applications. the Amazon Appstore is merely another platform for developers to release their applications on.

So to answer you question briefly, YES, you can use the AdMob Api, integrate into your Android app and release it on the Amazon Appstore, or Appstore for that matter (naturally, the ones that support Android apps. ;-) )

Comment: Yes, but Amazon has a strict policy against links to other marketplaces. And lots of ads in AdMob link to Google Play.  
Here is the answer I got from Amazon's customer support:  
"If the AdMob is strictly advertising, and doesn't relate to your app, and is just in your app, although may fail our testing, can be reviewed, and the failure maybe overridden."

Comment: AdMob lets you disable (filter) ads from being shown. You can simply use that function and disable all ads that point to the Google PLay URL's. You can read up more about filtering ad's at: http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1307260&topic=1307248&ctx=topic

Comment: The new version of AdMob click the "Monetise" tab and then the "Allow & Block Ads" link on the left side menu. More info here: https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3150235   You want to block "play.google.com"

Comment: 2020, answer is no. Use Amazon Mobile Ads.

Comment: 2021, answer is apparently yes, as now when setting a new admob app you are asked about which platforms you are launching on and Amazon app store is in the list along with VIVo app store, MI store, Oppo store

Comment: 2022-02-08 update: "Important: The Amazon Mobile Ads Network was deprecated on September 30, 2021." (https://developer.amazon.com/fr/apps-and-games/mobile-ads). "Amazon Publisher Services" kind of replaces it.

Answer (score 33):

I have 24 apps on amazon all with admob without any filter. Amazon's policy against links to other market places not apply to ads. They only apply if you directly place a link in your app. Like, button "more games" that lead to your games on google play.

Answer (score 1):

My google account got suspended so I uploaded the same apk to Amazon, now my app only show kindle ads.

I think they're influencing which ads shows up through their market, even if I am using admob. Not 100% sure right now. I've tried to at least 100 times restarting my app and even force closing my app a bunch of times but it only shows Amazon Kindle ads.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your app also success published to google play store/apple app store.

No, if above not fullfill. Go for Amazon Mobile Ads, it is better.

Comment: Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: I can't understand anything of what you have write