# Several doubts about admob policies

Tags: android, admob

I am developing an app for Android about jokes, like these:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.jokes
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hrstudios.chistes

1- Some jokes include "adult words" but no pictures. So... I would like to know if I can use AdMob in my app.

2- Also, I have two google accounts. I was using one of them for Adsense/Admob, and I have created another one for publish apps in Google Play with a different e-mail. Can I put the admob adds from the first account in the second account applications?

3- Admob policies don't allow you to put adds in app with content created by other people. Is this a problem for my jokes app? Jokes haven't got any copyright.

Comment: Question is blatantly off topic as it has nothing to do with programming. You better take this question to Admob support team.

Comment: @Setu There are several question without any programming topic here, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848157/can-i-use-admob-in-android-apps-published-on-amazon-appstore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes that is unlikely to violate any anti-pornography policy
2. Yes
3. Not a problem. The policy is about copyrighted content.

But IANAL

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Are you completely sure about the second question? I can't allow get banned. What do you mean with "But IANAL"? Thanks again @William

Comment: Definitely sure about answer number two. IANAL means "I am not a lawyer".

Comment: Thanks again man. I would like to say you that I receive "No" answer in the admob group for the question 1. See it https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/WkJtJ5_zU-4  Definitely each person thinks something different about it, I will have to risk.