# Can I use both Google AdMob and Amazon Mobile Ads in my Android app

Tags: android, google-play, admob, amazon-mobile-ads

I found this link:

[Can I use AdMob in android apps published on Amazon Appstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848157/can-i-use-admob-in-android-apps-published-on-amazon-appstore)

The answer is Yes - It is good to know that but my question is:

Can I use **both Google AdMob and Amazon Mobile Ads** in my android App that will be publish on the Google Play Store?

Does it violate Google Play Developer Program Policies? Anyone has done this?

Answer (score 5):

If you are displaying 2 ads at the same time then it's

- against AdMob and Amazon Mobile Ads policies and will likely get your account banned,
- will almost certainly alienate your users.

If you aren't displaying them both at the same time then you are effectively mediating. In this case both AdMob and Amazon Mobile Ads can be used in conjunction with each other. In fact, they even provide mediation solutions just for this purpose.

References: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/mediation 
https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/mobile-ads/docs/with-other-sdks