# Can I use Facebook Audience Network (FAN) in android apps published on AppGallery of Huawei?

Tags: android, admob, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery, amazon-mobile-ads

It's a simple question, but I can't find an answer anywhere and get confused.. Can I use Facebook Audience Network (FAN) in my apps on AppGallery of Huawei? If not, what ad networks can I use? and get earn from it.

Few Other Questions in my mind:

1)Should i have to use signed apk or test apk on AppGallery of Huawei?

2)Should i have to use admob or Amazon Mobile ads kit in Amazon App Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1：Can I use Facebook Audience Network (FAN) in android apps published
> on AppGallery of Huawei?

Huawei has no restrictions on third-party ad platforms. You can use [HUAWEI Ads Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-introduction-0000001050064960?ha_source=hms1), or Facebook Audience Network (FAN), but Facebook App should be installed already.

> Q2：Should i have to use signed apk or test apk on AppGallery of
> Huawei?

If you want to release your app, please use signed apk. If you want to debug your app, please use test apk.

> Q3：Should i have to use admob or Amazon Mobile ads kit in Amazon App
> Store?

You can use Admob or Amazon Mobile Ads Kit. Please refer to this question: [Can I use AdMob in android apps published on Amazon Appstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848157/can-i-use-admob-in-android-apps-published-on-amazon-appstore)

Comment: Thank you so much, Its really helpful and I really appreciate you that you help me in this  @shirley

Comment: One more question If i use Google Firebase in my App and upload it on App Gallery, Does my App work perfectly on new Huawei devices ? Or does Huawei has services like Firebase??

Comment: @AwaisChorahi If your app integrates GMS, it can be uploaded  on AppGallery, while it cannot run on new Huawei phones(Mate 30, P40, Mate 40...). They are banned from using GMS. If you want your app to run on these phones, integrate [Huawei Mobile Services (HMS)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050048870?ha_source=hms1). Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63461164/13329100) answer help you!

Comment: Thanks again to guide me, So I can use Drive Kit instead of Firebase in new Huawei phones.

Comment: @AwaisChorahi why don't you accept this answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the ads of Facebook Audience Network in your apps. Also, Huawei has its own [Ads Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-adskit). You can quickly integrate Huawei Ads into your app and get revenue from it. For more details, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-dev-process-0000001050064964).

If you want to release your app on AppGallery, you have to sign your apk. But, you can test your app using mainstream Huawei devices provided by Huawei through [Cloud Debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-introduction) before it's published.

Comment: Thank you so much, Now my mind is cleared, These questions were bothering me

Answer (score 1):

Huawei AppGallery Connect(AGC) has same services like firebase, you can find the services introduction at [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-introduction).